# How do you sort an arraylist to be diverse instead of similar?

Tags: java, arraylist

So for one of my projects I have to make teams for a game based off of last names, They are supposed to be as diverse as possible, so the "smith" family will only be added onto the same team as another "smith" family if there is no other team without a "smith" already.

I am given an ArrayList with a list of Participants, whose last names are included. I just need to figure out how to sort this so that the ArrayList is diverse and I would just run through the ArrayList and assign them to the teams

```
ArrayList<Participant> list = tourney.getUnattatchedParticipants();
//need to sort list somehow
```

Comment: What have you tried? If the participants where standing in front of you on the paying field, how would you approach the problem of sort them into teams?  Could you translate that to code?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach your Problem like this;

1. Create a Data Container that keeps all the teams. Since we are not sure how many teams we will have, I would make this data container Dynamic (e.g. `ArrayList`)
2. I would start iterating your `ArrayList` with Participants and for each I would check Team Nr.1 if it contains a Participant which has a similiar (same, or contains part of the surname)  surname.
3. If it does, check Team Nr.2..
4. If we reach the last team and it already contains a Partipant which is similar to the last one, then we create Another team.

Maybe something like this:

```java
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Participant>> divideParticipantsIntoTeams(ArrayList<Participant> participants)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Participant>> groups = new ArrayList<>(); // This keeps our groups

        groups.add(new ArrayList<>()); // We create our first group.

        // We iterate over all given participants
        participants.forEach(participant ->
        {
            boolean contains = true; // Variable that shows us if we already have it in a group

            // We iterate over all the groups and check if it is contained in them
            for(ArrayList<Participant> group: groups)
            {
                 // Checks if a participant is found with a similar surname
                 contains = containsParticipant(group, participant);

                 // If it doesn't contain such a participant then we add it to the group and we go out of the loop.
                 if(!contains)
                 {
                     group.add(participant);
                     break;
                 }
            }

            // If we iterate all the groups and when finished they all contain some similar Participant, create a new one.
            if(contains)
            {
                groups.add(new ArrayList<>());

                ArrayList<Participant> newGroup = groups.get(groups.size() - 1); // Getting the just created group
                newGroup.add(participant); // Adding the participant to it
            }

        });

        return groups;
    }

    public boolean containsParticipant(ArrayList<Participant> group, Participant participant)
    {
        for(Participant groupParticipant: group)
        {
            // this could use some fine tuning, depends on how you want it.
            if(groupParticipant.getLastName().contains(participant.getLastName()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```